# Desabilitar Identity de coluna SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como faço para desabilitar a propriedade `identity` de uma coluna no `SQL Serve`r?

Já tentei:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF
```

Mas não funcionou. Não sei se serve somente para inserção, mas preciso fazer um update.

Comment: Para fazer update você não precisar desabilitar o identity. como você esta tentando fazer seu update?

Comment: Assim: UPDATE produto SET id_produto = 500 WHERE id_produto = 1;

E recebo o seguinte erro: Mensagem 8102, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Não é possível atualizar a coluna de identidade 'id_produto'.

Comment: você rodou o comando SET IDENTITY_INSERT produto  ON

Comment: Para desabilitar creio que seja SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON, correto?

Comment: Sim, tinha editado.

Answer (score 9):

Ex.1:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl ON  --Desabilita o IDENTITY

INSERT INTO masterTbl (id, name) VALUES (1, 'MNO') --Consegue inserir

SET IDENTITY_INSERT masterTbl OFF  --Habilita o IDENTITY
```

Ex.2:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT produto ON --Desabilita o IDENTITY

insert into produto (Codigo, Nome) --Consegue inserir
SELECT Codigo, Nome
from produto2
where codigo in (46296,46298,46301)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT produto OFF --Habilita o IDENTITY
```

**OBS:** É NECESSÁRIO ESPECIFICAR AS COLUNAS DO INSERT, CASO SEJA UM INSERT INTO SELECT, NECESSÁRIO ESPECIFICAR AS COLUNAS TANTO DO INSERT QUANTO DO SELECT.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, você não quer **desabilitar** o Identity Insert, você quer **habilitá-lo**.

Não existe nenhuma forma de fazer isso sem "*workarounds*" (isso mesmo, você vai ter que fazer uma gambiarra).

Você pode usar um `Insert Into Select` (eu não sei como isso se chama de verdade) para criar um registro idêntico com o novo Id, e depois apagar o antigo.

Veja meu exemplo, eu troco o valor do `Id` de **`1`** para **`500`**, é a melhor forma que consigo pensar agora.

Note que isso **não irá funcionar** se existirem FK's com referência para este Id que está sendo trocado.

```
Set Identity_insert Tabela On
Go

Insert Into Tabela (Id, Nome, Etc, Etc2) 
     Select 500, (Nome, Etc, Etc2) -- 500 é o novo Id
     From Tabela Where Id = 1 -- 1 é o Id antigo

Delete Tabela Where Countryid = 1 

Set Identity_insert Geocountry Off
Go
```

Comment: É que não preciso inserir, preciso editar, a princípio.

Comment: É impossível, eu já falei. Você vai precisar inserir um registro idêntico com outro Id (como faço na minha resposta).

Comment: Pois é, vou ter que achar outra maneira para resolver este meu problema.

Comment: Qual é o problema da minha solução?

Comment: Eu tenho que pegar o valor de uma outra coluna e ele pode ser igual a um ID que já existe. Mas na verdade, nem é na sua solução em si. Vou ter que repensar uma forma de fazer.

Comment: Acho que a solução Boa também...

Answer (score 0):

É necessário autorizar temporariamente a inserção de valores de identidade, para isso no SQL Server Management Studio clique com o botão direito sobre a tabela e clique em Design conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso clique na PK da tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em seguida, altere o campo (É indentidade) para Não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Remova sua chave primaria.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Salve a alteração e m seguida faça seu update.

Comment: Tem certeza que é possível fazer atualização de colunas identity?

Comment: Realmente não funciona. Talvez não seja possível, como o @jbueno falou...

Comment: Isso que está nos prints eu também já fiz

Comment: @elvex , Se a ultima alteração não resolver provavelmente você esta fazendo algo muito errado